# Book series with a shape shifting dragon girl

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons, shape-shifter

Does anyone know the name of the book series about a girl who finds out she can turn into a dragon and has to learn how to? She falls in love with a human guy who is fine with her being a dragon and she ends up having to fly to an island where other dragon people are to find them and save their race...

Comment: This is a nice overview, if a bit brief. Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you read these? Were they new at the time? How many books were there? How did she find out about the other dragon people? Can you remember anymore specific plot points? etc.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the [Jennifer Scales](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43000-jennifer-scales) series, but some of the details are off.  You might look at [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/190160/78394) if that sounds familiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this may be *[Lost Truth](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/111020.Lost_Truth)*, fourth book of the *[Truth](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41182-truth)* series by Dawn Cook.

[image: Cover of *Lost Truth*]

> Alissa is steadily advancing in her magical studies with the last surviving Master at the legendary Hold. But she's haunted by dreams--dreams revealing that other Masters have survived...
>
> Alissa's dreams lead her to a distant island, where she and a rescue party discover countless Masters, alive and part of a flourishing magical society. But instead of being welcomed, Alissa finds that she herself may need to be rescued. The Masters' leader, Keribdis, believes that she should be Alissa's teacher, whether Alissa likes it or not. And when Alissa rebels, she endangers not only her magic, but also her life..

Alissa learned to transform into a dragon in previous books. :) I had my own query, [looking for *First Truth*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76496/trying-to-remember-a-book-involving-a-girl-from-a-distrusted-race-becoming-a-mag/76508#76508), first book in the series, so I did a Google search for *dawn cook girl dragon island* and found the fourth book mentioned an island and her people. The love interest is Strell, an itinerant musician who had one of her father's maps in the first book. I think one of the later books had a young Raku (dragon) that acted as a romantic rival.

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you so much!!!! This is the book! ❤️❤️❤️ You’re awesome @FuzzyBoots!!!